# Prove that $(z-x^3,y-x^2)$ is a prime ideal

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am trying to prove that the ideal in ${\mathbb C}[x,y,z]$ generated by $z-x^3$ and $y-x^2$ is prime. I know I could take a suitable quotient and show it's  domain. But I am rather stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider ${\mathbb C}[x,y,z] \to {\mathbb C}[x]$ induced by $x\mapsto x$, $y\mapsto x^2$, $z\mapsto x^3$.

Comment: I see...the map is surjective and the kernel is $(z-x^3,y-x^2)$, so the quotient is isomorphic to ${\mathbb C}[x]$, that is a domain.